# better Understanding a proof of Hartshorne's book proposition 2.2. (b)

Tags: algebraic-geometry

> I have been reading the book Algebraic Geometry by Robin Hartshorne
>   and I have found  the following proposition:

[image]

> For part b) the proof goes as follows:

[image]

> I really don't follow proof that $\psi $ surjective. That goes as
>   follows:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

> In the proof of surjectivity in first paragraph  how can we replace $ h_i^n$ by $h_i$(since $D(h_i) = D(h_i^n)$ )
>    I hope someone can help me understanding this parts of this proof.
>   Thanks in advance.

Comment: First, this is a too long question, It might be not many will try to read it all, so try to concentrate on one thing and ask about it. Second, it is my opinion that Hartshorne's book can be a very good one for consult, but a terrible, awful book for a beginner. If you haven't studied algebraic geometry before, I'd advice you to leave that book aside and study first from another, most friendly book.

Answer (score 1):

This is the simplifying assumption they would like to make for the rest of the proof: there exist elements $h_i'\in A$ such that $D(f)=\bigcup_i D(h_i')$, and the restriction of $s$ to $D(h_i')$ is equal to $a_i'/h_i'$ for some $a_i'\in A$.

So we already have elements $h_i$ such that $D(f)=\bigcup_i D(h_i)$ and $s|_{D(h_i)}=ca_i/h_i^n$, so if we take $a_i'=ca_i$ and $h_i'=h_i^n$, then we certainly have $s|_{D(h_i)}=a_i'/h_i'$, and if we can prove that $D(h_i)=D(h_i')$ then we will have the conditions above met. But it is easy to verify that $D(h)=D(h^n)$ for any $h\in A$ and $n\in\Bbb Z^+$.